# Append column to data frame with text based on another column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In this dataframe, how to go about appending a column named "class_name", with a text string, that is based on another column.

| x | y | z | not used | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.8481877 | -0.47685334 | 0.63422906 | 1.0396314 | 1 |
| -2.320888 | 0.65347993 | 1.1519914 | 0.12997247 | 1 |
| 1.5827686 | 1.4119303 | -1.7410104 | -4.6962333 | 2 |
| -0.1337152 | 0.13315737 | -1.6648949 | -1.4205348 | 2 |
| -0.4028037 | 1.332986 | 1.3618442 | 0.3292255 | 1 |
| -0.015517877 | 1.346349 | 1.4083523 | 0.87017965 | 0 |
| -0.2669228 | 0.5478992 | -0.06730786 | -1.5959451 | 0 |
| -0.03318152 | 0.3263167 | -2.116833 | -5.4616213 | 1 |

There are the values the new column will take based on the values in the 'Label' column:

```
0 == 'avocados'
1 == 'apples'
2 == ' grapes
```

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('embed1_2.csv')

df.loc[df.y_train == 103, 'class_name'] = 'avocados'
df.loc[df.y_train == 103, 'class_name'] = 'apples'
df.loc[df.y_train == 103, 'class_name'] = 'grapes'
```

How to get the appended column to show up with the converted text?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a dictionary and then use map in creating a new columns

```
dict = {
0 : 'avocados',
1 : 'apples',
2 : 'grapes' 
}
df['val']=df['Label'].map(dict)
df
```

```
            x           y          z    not used    Label   val
0   -3.848188   -0.476853   0.634229    1.039631    1   apples
1   -2.320888   0.653480    1.151991    0.129972    1   apples
2   1.582769    1.411930    -1.741010   -4.696233   2   grapes
3   -0.133715   0.133157    -1.664895   -1.420535   2   grapes
4   -0.402804   1.332986    1.361844    0.329226    1   apples
5   -0.015518   1.346349    1.408352    0.870180    0   avocados
6   -0.266923   0.547899    -0.067308   -1.595945   0   avocados
7   -0.033182   0.326317    -2.116833   -5.461621   1   apples
```